# How can I create a non-member function with variable arguments in a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, printf, unresolved-external, variadic-functions

I'm writing my own String class in my DLL and I want to be able to format the text like printf/etc does, but no matter how I try to implement this, I get "unresolved external symbol" on my functions with ellipses when trying to link my DLL, despite the fact that they are defined. I have tried implementing the string formatter as a constructor in my String class like this:

```
class DLLEXP String
{
public:
    String();
    String(const String &other);
    String(const String &format, ...);
    // more member funcs
}
```

I have also tried implementing it as a constructor in a separate class, StringFormat:

```
class DLLEXP StringFormat
{
public:
    StringFormat();
    StringFormat(const StringFormat &other);
    StringFormat(const String &format, ...);
};

class DLLEXP String
{
public:
    String();
    String(const String &other);
    String(const StringFormat &format);
    // more member funcs
};
```

I've also tried just regular functions:

```
DLLEXP String StringFormat(const String &format, ...);
```

and even:

```
DLLEXP char* __cdecl StringFormat(const char *format, ...);
```

Is there some kind of secret to importing variable-argument functions from a DLL properly or is this simply impossible on Windows? Each of the above functions work perfectly as soon as I remove the ellipses... but I need those. Also these functions work fine in shared libraries on Linux. I've been tearing my hair out for hours on this so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't answer your question directly, but can give you a workaround. Implement it as inline function and instead expose a function taking a `va_list` instead, similar to the pair `sprintf`/`vsprintf`. You could also look at those two to find out how they are implemented. That said, why don't you use templates instead of type-unsafe format strings?

Comment: What exactly is the error? What is undefined?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What kind of template could I write that gives the same flexibility as a variable argument?

Comment: @Praxeolitic Any function with "..." in it is an unresolved external despite the fact that it is defined.

Comment: Check out Boost.Format, for example. With C++ 11, I believe there are even variadic templates. But still, it is not the same amount of flexibility, which is the price you pay for type safety.